# Deleting index from ElasticSearch (via Kibana) automatically being recreated?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elastic-stack

I have created an ElasticSearch instance via AWS and have pushed some test data into it in order to play around with Kibana. I'm done playing around now and want to delete all my data and start again. I have run a delete command on my index:

Command

```
DELETE /uniqueindex
```

Response

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

However almost immediately my index seems to re-appear and documents start appearing in the count of documents as well.

Command

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

Response:

```
health status index       uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .kibana_1   e3LQWRvgSvqSL8CFTyw_SA   1   0          3            0     15.2kb         15.2kb
yellow open   uniqueindex Y4tlNxAXQVKUs_DjVQLNnA   5   1        713            0    421.7kb        421.7kb
```

It's like it's auto generating after the delete. Clearly a setting or something, but being new to ElasticSearch/Kibana I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: How you pushed the data? If you delete an index it will be only recreated if you still are sending data to the same index name.

Comment: I agree with @leandrojmp. when you send the data to deleted indices, it will be created again.

Answer (score 2):

By default indices in Elasticsearch can be [created automatically](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation) just by PUTing or POSTing a document.

You can change this behavior with `action.auto_create_index` where you can disable this entirely (indices need to be created with a PUT command) or just whitelist specific indices.

Quoting from the linked docs:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "twitter,index10,-index1*,+ind*" 
    }
}

PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "false" 
    }
}
```

`+` is allowing automatic index creation while `-` forbids it.